# Calculating an integral with possible approximations

Tags: integration

My lecturer stated that for $\alpha>1$, $\epsilon<<1$

$$I=\int_0^\varepsilon\frac{{\rm d}t}{(1+t)^\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha-1}$$

Now I'm confused on how to get this solution. I have tried letting $u=1+t$ so that $du=dt$ then we have

$$I=\int_1^{1+\varepsilon}\frac{{\rm d}u}{u^\alpha} = \left[\frac{u^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}\right]^{1+\varepsilon}_1=\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}+\frac1{\alpha-1}$$

Now I'm guessing her solution was just an approximation and maybe we can ignore the first term but I'm not too sure of the reasoning yet. We know that $\alpha>1$ so $1-\alpha<0$ we may write

$$(1+\varepsilon)^{1-\alpha}=\frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon)^{\alpha-1}}$$

now does this give zero? I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Looks as if your teacher meant to say $\epsilon=+\infty$?

Comment: for small $\epsilon$ the result should be just $1$ by simple taylor expansion